# Notepad++ Search And Replace with regular expression

Tags: notepad++

Find:

```
{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},
```

Replace:

```
{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},

{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},

{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;},
```

or Replace:

```
{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;

{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;

{&quot;aaa&quot Text Text &quot;
```

I use find:

```
{&quot;aaa\&.*\&quot;
```

and replace by:

```
{&quot;aaa\&.*\&quot;\n
```

but can't replace. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace

```
&quot;\},\{&quot;aaa&quot
```

by

```
&quot;\},\n\{&quot;aaa&quot
```

[image]